# Execution of multiple increment operators

Tags: c, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

How would the output of

```
int i = 6;
i += ++i + ++i + i++ + --i;
printf("%d", i);
```

be evaluated. When I do it on paper I get 39.
But the output after executing is 40.

Comment: This will produce an undefined behavior.

Comment: @Surajeet Bharati why? Is anything in it ambiguous?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Also look into this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points